# Psexec to copy files to a remote machine

Tags: windows, psexec

I want to copy a file from the local machine to a remote machine through PSExec.

But I get the error

```
psexec64.exe \\remote_ip -i -h -u admin -p pass11 cmd /c xcopy /c "C:\Folder" "\\remote_ip\c$\Folder"

PsExec v2.43 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2023 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


Invalid path
0 File(s) copied
cmd exited on remote_ip with error code 4.
```

Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Why on earth would you use PSExec to do this?  I don't get it.  Are you trying to pull the file rather than push it?  So confused.

Comment: Totally unclear : If you want to copy a local folder, why not just do `copy "C:\Folder" "\\remote_ip\c$\Folder"` ?

Comment: How are you connecting to the remote machine?  Copying does not automatically connect.

Comment: PSEXEC is not a file transfer application. you will not be able to do this. just like SSH doesn't support file transfer (thus the need for the separate but dependent SCP\SFTP), a remote shell won't be able to handle your needs. you need a remote file transfer utility instead.